# Why is my JavaScript line working and breaking JSLint with "Unexpected assignment expression"

Tags: javascript, jslint

While trying to rewrite some JavaScript, one late (late) night, I converted this:

```
    var set = feature.dict_name;
    var target;

    if (set) {
      target = app[feature.dict_name] = {};
    } else {
      target = app;
    }
```

into this:

```
var target = (feature.set_on? app[feature.dict_name] = {} : undefined) || app;
```

and never wondered, because although I'm rubbing my eyes now once JSLint complained, everything worked fine.

**So my question**:
Why does it work and correctly sets `target` and `set` and is it such bad practice?

Comment: The two snippets are not equivalent (what is `feature.set_on`?), but to be honest the original code was better than yours. I would simply inline `set` and be done with it. Your version is really hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the fact I pointed out in my comment that the snippets are not indeed equal, the reason why it works lies in the way Javascript resolves the value of `x || y`.

While in many languages it resolves to either `true` or `false`, Javascript will resolve it to `x` if and only if `x` is truthy, and to `y` otherwise.

Here are some examples:

```
console.log( 5 || 10 ); // 5, because 5 is truthy
console.log( 0 || 10 ); // 10, because 0 is falsy and 10 is truthy
console.log( 0 || 0 ); // 0
console.log( 0 || "" ); // ""
```

Assuming you actually meant the following one-liner

```
var target = (feature.dict_name ? app[feature.dict_name] = {} : undefined) || app;
```

it would indeed be equivalent to the original snippet.

- If `feature.dict_name` is truthy, you do the assignment `app[...] = {}`, which is an expression that returns its value (`{}`) and because `{}` is a truthy value, `{} || app` will resolve to `{}` to make the final assignment to `target`  work.
- Otherwise, you get `undefined || app` which resolves to `app` since `undefined` is falsy.

In terms of code quality I think the rewirte only made things worse, to be honest. Obviously not even you, who wrote it, can understand how it works anymore. Saving yourself a couple of lines and lose readability instead is a terrible trade-off. I would've rewritten it to

```
var target;
if (feature.dict_name) {
  target = app[feature.dict_name] = {};
} else {
  target = app;
}
```

which is easy to read and understand and therefore easy to maintain. In fact, I would extract a function for this, effectively probably adding a line or so.

I don't know what JSLint complains about, but I don't need JSLint to tell you that I would indeed consider your version bad practice.